# Problems with array references in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I am trying to count how many time DE10 and each of the keys in my ICD10 hash occurs in the same line in my file2.tsv. I further have to divide it by male/female (M/K).
I therefore made a hash called results. Each of the keys in this is named after the key in the ICD10 hash, and they refers to an array of 2 elements, the first counting the male, the second counting the females.

But I get this warning:

```
Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"
```

due to this line:

```
  $results{$key}[1] +=1;
```

I am a little weak on this reference part, can someone help me with my mistake? thanks a lot

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

###################
# loading my hash #
###################

my %icd10;

open(IN, '<', 'myfile.tsv') or die;
while (defined (my $line = <IN>)) {
chomp $line;
$icd10{$line} = 1;
}
close IN;

################
### COUNTING
#################

my %results;

open(IN, '<', 'myfile2.tsv') or die;
while (defined (my $line = <IN>)) {
chomp $line;
my @line = split('\t', $line);
my %hash;
for (my $i = 2; $i < scalar(@line); $i++){ 
    $hash{$line[$i]} = 1;
}

if (grep (m/^DE10/, keys %hash)) {
    foreach my $key (keys %icd10){
        if (grep (m/^$key/, keys %hash)) {
            if (exists $results{$key}) {
                if ($line[1] eq 'M') {
                    $results{$key}[1] +=1;
                }
                elsif ($line[1] eq 'K'){
                    $results{$key}[2] +=1;
                }
            }
            else{
                if ($line[1] eq 'M') {
                    $results{$key}=(1,0);
                }
                elsif ($line[1] eq 'K'){
                    $results{$key}=(0,1);
                }
            }
```

Comment: The parentheses in these two sentences `$results{$key}=(1,0);` and `$results{$key}=(0,1);` should be brackets, if you want `$results{$key}` to be a reference to an array.

Comment: Is this line a typo `if (grep (m/^DE10, keys %hash)) {` ? It should be `if (grep (/^DE10/, keys %hash)) {
`

Comment: M42: sorry, that was a copy paste error.

Comment: leeduhem: so it should be $results{$key}={1,0} ? It doesnt fix the problem

Comment: It should be `$results{$key} = [1,0];`

Answer (score 2):

If you want `$results{$key}` to be a reference to an array, then the parentheses in these two identical sentences `$results{$key}=(1,0);` should be square brackets, like this: `$results{$key}=[1,0];`.

To create a reference to an array, you can use backslash operator:

```
$arrayref = \@array;
```

To create a reference to an anonymous array you should use square brackets:

```
$arrayref = [ 'ele1', 'ele2' ];
```

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) for further details.

Comment: Okay, I might be really stupid , but Im not sure what I should change. 
if I write $results{$key}=[1,0]; I still have the same problem.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by brackets

Comment: @user2335015 Change both `$results{$key}=(1,0);` to `$results{$key}=[1,0];` does not work?

Comment: Arh sorry in my real code, there were a couple more places I need to change it. It seems to be running now. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2335015 Already changed 'brackets' to 'square brackets', I hope the meaning of this one is clear.